# Hiding types from Objective-C framework header files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks, header-files

I'm writing a media player framework for a project I'm working on. This depends on VLC. One of my classes' header file looks like this

```
#import <vlc/vlc.h>

@interface MediaPlayerVLC : MediaPlayer
{
    libvlc_media_player_t *player;
    libvlc_media_t *media;
}

@end
```

I need the instance variables in the class, and I need the `#import <vlc/vlc.h>`, because they're defined in there. But I don't want users of this framework to have to import all of VLC's headers just for these two types. I've seen a few solutions to this problem around...

- Forward declaration, such as `@class`. Unfortunately, these types are `typedef struct` types, I can't seem to find any way to forward declare them
- declare the ivars as `void *`, then cast them whenever I want to use them. I'd like to avoid this if possible, as we lose type-safety and implementation files become full of ugly casts.
- I've seen this in Apple's frameworks...

  ```
  @interface CAAnimation : NSObject <NSCoding, NSCopying, CAMediaTiming, CAAction>
  {
  @private
    void *_attr;
    uint32_t _flags;
  }
  ```

  What does `_attr` point to? I guess it would be a struct of ivars, I'm curious what advantages this has...
- Two header files for the class, one public and one private. The private one would look like the above, and the public would just have `void *` pointers. This is pretty ugly, as I'd have to be very careful to keep them both in sync.

What's considered best practise? Is there an approach I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use class extensions. You should try doing this:

MediaPlayerVLC.h:

```
@interface MediaPlayerVLC : MediaPlayer
{
}

@end
```

MediaPlayerVLC.m:

```
#import "MediaPlayerVLC.h"
#import <vlc/vlc.h>

@interface MediaPlayerVLC ()
{
    libvlc_media_player_t *player;
    libvlc_media_t *media;
}

@end

@implementation MediaPlayerVLC

// The implementation

@end
```

From [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2):

> Class extensions are like anonymous categories, except that the
>   methods they declare must be implemented in the main @implementation
>   block for the corresponding class.
>   Using the Clang/LLVM 2.0 compiler,
>   you can also declare properties and instance variables in a class
>   extension.

That's using a class extension category to declare extra ivars in the implementation file.

Comment: +1, since when can I declare ivars in a class extension? I must have missed that.

Comment: Sure not a problem. For reference it's since the non-fragile instance variables ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Non-fragile_instance_variables ) support was added to LLVM.

Comment: also a good read for this topic: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/dynamic-ivars-solving-fragile-base.html, but ivars in class extensions are not covered there, so I had no idea, it was working like this.

Comment: ivars in @implementation and class extensions is newer than the addition of non-fragile ivar support...

Answer (score 3):

With the newest compiler you can also declare ivars in your class's `@implementation` section:

```
// MediaPlayerVLC.m

#import "MediaPlayerVLC.h"
#import <vlc/vlc.h>

@implementation MediaPlayerVLC
{
    libvlc_media_player_t *player;
    libvlc_media_t *media;
}

...

@end
```

Comment: You can? Never heard of that. Crazy stuff... Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

You can put ivars in implementation like

```
@implementation Something
{
    int a;
}
```